# How to find an optimal solution of the dual from the primal tableau?

Tags: linear-programming

[image]

The tableau above is an optimal tableau of a LP problem. If I want to find the optimal solution of dual, I know, I can rewrite this in terms of the original problem and remove the slack variables $x_4,x_5$ and then find the dual which is 2 dimensional which can be done by graphical methods.

But, how can we find the optimal solution of dual without doing all this? that is, by just looking at the tableau above?

Comment: Take the negative of the coefficients for the slack variables in the objective function in the optimal primal tableau.  These are the optimal values for the basic variables of the dual problem, i.e. the optimal solution for the dual.  You can test the answer by constructing the objective function for the dual and verifying that the dual and the primal have the same optimal value.